# Best way to Use Nginx Conf in a pod

Tags: linux, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-config, configmap

Currently I've nginx running in a pod on EKS cluster. I'm using configmap to mount values as conf files to pod. But now as the size of conf file is increasing I'm getting the following error.
**standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: argument list too long** 
If I remove some of the entries in conf files it works. So is there any other way to do this because size of the conf file will increase and I think configmap has a size limit of 1MiB.

Comment: Can you elaborate how does `entries in conf files` can increase the length of the arguments passed to a program that to be exec? Help may be provided if you can tell more about what program is this.

Comment: You can check this, as the number of services increases, so does the location block in server section under nginx.conf. I'm following similar approach.
https://gist.github.com/petitviolet/d36f33d145d0bbf4b54eb187b79d0244

Comment: The sample config is 187 characters only, can you actually hit **1 mega bytes** limit with just location section...

Comment: Yes that was just for sample to give you the idea. My location block is long and there are around 100 of them and still increasing.

Comment: Hi @DevS, could you please provide example ConfigMap and configuration file - the one that you are mounting and the increased one that is not working, also please provide example deployment / pod resource yaml file that your are applying. Please provide information **which** commands are you running and **where** are you getting this error. Please make sure that [your issue is reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so others can replicate this locally and find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.